# function to split dataframe using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have dataframe (63 cols x 7446 rows). What I want to do is slice the dataframe to make new dataframes consisting of specific columns specified by their location using `.iloc()`.

I have written the following code but it doesn't work, I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [12] of <class 'int'>
```

Basically I want the function to split the dataframe, save them as new variables and then save those as csv files with `.to_csv()`. I haven't gotten to that part of the saving the dataframes yet, but any input on that would be very much appreciated.

This is the code I have:

```
names = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
nums = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60]

#Function to split df into the 20 joints and save them as csv
def splitAndSave(df):
    for i in names:
        for j in nums:
            #selects columns to be put into a new dataframe, concatenating them if they are not adjacent
            locals()["split"+str(i)] = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0:3],df.iloc[:,nums[j]:nums[j]+3]], axis=1)

    #save outputs as csv?
```

The desired output would be to have multiple variable like so:

`split1` is a dataframe with the following columns: `col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5`

and then

`split2` is a dataframe with the following columns: `col0, col1, col2, col6, col7, col8`

etc, all the way up to `split20`.

Let me know if this makes sense, and thanks in advance for the help!

**NOTE:** I haven't included a snippet of the dataframe because it's so big, but let me know if it is necessary so that you can have a working example.

**EDIT:** After fixing the silly mistake with `loc` and `iloc` I now get the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**UPDATE:** Having changed the code a bit based on the answers and some more research I now have this:

```
d = {}
#Function to split df into the 20 joints and save them as csv

    def splitAndSave(df):
        for i in names:
            for j in nums:
                #selects columns to be put into a new dataframe, concatenating them if they are not adjacent
                d["split{0}".format(i)] = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0:3],df.iloc[:,j:j+3]], axis=1)
        return d
```

The issue now is that while it dynamically updates the variable names (`split1, 2` etc) it doesn't do the same for `j`. The outputs I get are

```
{'split1':       col0   col1        col2  col61  col62  col63
'split2':       col0   col1        col2  col61  col62  col63 ... }
```

Why does it not loop through `nums` to update `j` and why does it only choose the last three columns?

**DATA:** Here is a snippet of the dataframe, it is made up of 63 columns, the first three below (Frame, Time, SMPTE) and then the other 60 are similar to the `bar_head_x/y/z`, just named differently. I've only included these six columns as an idea of the dataframe:

```
  Frame Time    SMPTE       bar_head_x  bar_head_y  bar_head_z
0   1   0.00    02:45:25:03 -203.3502   1554.3486   1102.8210
1   2   0.01    02:45:25:03 -203.4280   1554.3492   1103.0592
2   3   0.02    02:45:25:03 -203.4954   1554.3234   1103.2794
3   4   0.03    02:45:25:04 -203.5022   1554.2974   1103.4522
4   5   0.04    02:45:25:04 -203.5014   1554.2948   1103.6594
```

The output at the moment is basically the same for each split_i (see UPDATE above). The desired output is:

```
{'split1':       col0   col1   col2  col3  col4  col5
 'split2':       col0   col1   col2  col6  col7  col8
 'split3':       col0   col1   col2  col9  col10  col11 ... }
```

Obviously, each column contains the according data from the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit # 2:**

Code below splits the DataFrame into parts. [Note: that in the sample DataFrame below, the same values are used, but it has different column names.]

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Frame': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'Time': [0.00, 0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04],
    'SMPTE': ['02:45:25:03','02:45:25:03','02:45:25:03','02:45:25:04','02:45:25:04'],
    'bar_head_x': [-203.3502, -203.4280,-203.4954,-203.5022,-203.5014],
    'bar_head_y': [1554.3486, 1554.3492,1554.3234,1554.2974,1554.2948],
    'bar_head_z': [1102.8210, 1103.0592,1103.2794,1103.4522,1103.6594],
    'bar_head_x1': [-9203.3502, -203.4280,-203.4954,-203.5022,-99203.5014],
    'bar_head_y1': [91554.3486, 1554.3492,1554.3234,1554.2974,991554.2948],
    'bar_head_z1': [91102.8210, 1103.0592,1103.2794,1103.4522,991103.6594],
    'bar_head_x2': [-77203.3502, -203.4280,-203.4954,-203.5022,-77203.5014],
    'bar_head_y2': [771554.3486, 1554.3492,1554.3234,1554.2974,771554.2948],
    'bar_head_z2': [771102.8210, 1103.0592,1103.2794,1103.4522,771103.6594]
})

# Initialize
#nums = [3, 6, 9]
nums = np.linspace(3, df.shape[1]-3,3).astype(int)

# Function to split (copy-pased code from question above)
def splitAndSave(df):
    i=0 # counter
    d = {} # empty
    for j in nums:
        i+=1
        d["split{0}".format(i)] = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0:3],df.iloc[:,j:j+3]], axis=1)
    return d

# Call to function
d = splitAndSave(df)
```

Output

```
d

{'split1':    Frame  Time        SMPTE  bar_head_x  bar_head_y  bar_head_z
 0      1  0.00  02:45:25:03   -203.3502   1554.3486   1102.8210
 1      2  0.01  02:45:25:03   -203.4280   1554.3492   1103.0592
 2      3  0.02  02:45:25:03   -203.4954   1554.3234   1103.2794
 3      4  0.03  02:45:25:04   -203.5022   1554.2974   1103.4522
 4      5  0.04  02:45:25:04   -203.5014   1554.2948   1103.6594,
 'split2':    Frame  Time        SMPTE  bar_head_x1  bar_head_y1  bar_head_z1
 0      1  0.00  02:45:25:03   -9203.3502   91554.3486   91102.8210
 1      2  0.01  02:45:25:03    -203.4280    1554.3492    1103.0592
 2      3  0.02  02:45:25:03    -203.4954    1554.3234    1103.2794
 3      4  0.03  02:45:25:04    -203.5022    1554.2974    1103.4522
 4      5  0.04  02:45:25:04  -99203.5014  991554.2948  991103.6594,
 'split3':    Frame  Time        SMPTE  bar_head_x2  bar_head_y2  bar_head_z2
 0      1  0.00  02:45:25:03  -77203.3502  771554.3486  771102.8210
 1      2  0.01  02:45:25:03    -203.4280    1554.3492    1103.0592
 2      3  0.02  02:45:25:03    -203.4954    1554.3234    1103.2794
 3      4  0.03  02:45:25:04    -203.5022    1554.2974    1103.4522
 4      5  0.04  02:45:25:04  -77203.5014  771554.2948  771103.6594}
```

**Edit # 1:**

The problem seems to be use of `.loc` instead of `.iloc`.

Try replacing:

```
locals()["split"+str(i)] = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0:3],df.loc[:,nums[j]:nums[j]+3]], axis=1)
```

with this:

```
locals()["split"+str(i)] = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0:3],df.iloc[:,j:j+3]], axis=1)
```

Comment: I've edited the answer. The `for loop` is using `in` therefore directly using `j` works instead of `nums[j]`

Comment: So that works in the sense that it doesn't give me an error. But the output from the for loop isn't what I need, it keeps outputting the same columns, rather than iterating through them, so all the split_i's are the same...Can you see why it would do this?

Comment: With available information in the question, it is difficult to understand what data is passed to the function. It would help, to see a sample DataFrame and a desired output.

Comment: Yes of course, I added the information in the question, if that helps you now.

Comment: Thanks you. Looking into it now. And will update this comment if I can find anything.

Comment: Posted Edit # 2 with new code that splits the sample DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the `.loc` attribute, but using an integer range slicer:

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0:3], df.loc[:,nums[j]:nums[j]+3]], axis=1)
#                         HERE ^
```

You probably mean to use `.iloc` there as well.

Comment: yes that was a silly mistake i didn't notice, thanks!! However, I still get an error, see the edit in the post

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are in order, you can use the below method

```
split1 = df.iloc[:, 0:6]

split2 = df.iloc[:, 0:18]
```

if the columns are not in order then you can use this way

```
split1 = df[['col1', 'col2']]
split2 = df[['col0', 'col4']]
```

Comment: I have to do this maaaany times, so I'm trying to avoid doing it manually. That's why I'm trying to use functions and for loops :)